# Google JavaScript API - chrome.printerProvider

Tags: google-chrome, printing, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a printing extension, that can configure printing options and send a print job to the attached printers.

I have made sample extensions other than printing, but the printing API has no methods, just events, so it's not working for me.

Here is my script (Event.js):

```
chrome.printerProvider.onPrintRequested.addListener(
function( printJob, callback){
    var str = printJob.printerId + " , " + printJob.title ;
    alert('str: '+ str);
    console.log('str: '+str);
    appendToLog('str: '+ str );
    });


function callback(infos){
     console.log('Printing Completed!');
    }
```

As I understood from the documentation, this should be triggered on printing events. But when i print, nothing happens (they are not triggered).

Here is part of my manifest.json:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["event.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

 "permissions": [
     "printerProvider"
 ]
```

Google PrintProvider JS API: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/printerProvider

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong? or guide me to a useful resources?

Answer (score 2):

The printer you're providing has to register itself at `onGetPrintersRequested` event first.

Do you understand the purpose of this API? It will not allow you to modify print settings for existing printers. It's kind of a "driver" interface to provide (hence the name) a new printer to Chrome.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Xan. Apparently, I misunderstood this API. Is there anyway to control print settings on Chrome via JavaScript? On Firefox, I'm using an extension called "JS Print Setup" -  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/ , but couldn't find similar extension on chrome so i thought i can make it myself

Comment: I am interested in this API too, because Mozilla is going to deprecate XUL addons in Firefox in a year. I need a way to control which window to get printed and which printer to use. Basically I need something like `printers.getPrintersList()` and `printers.print(windowObj, printerName, printerSettings)`. Are there any plans to support such thing in WebExtensions API?

Comment: @suricactus Did you find a solution of printing in chrome via JS? I mean is there a replacement for "JS Print Setup"?

Comment: No, I haven't. I am no longer working on that project, so I cannot share any further details.